# Adding a deposit and withdrawal method to a form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, banking

Hi there I am very desperate for any help I can get. Ill try to explain this as best as I can. I'm currently trying to make a bank form using c #, the user can select an account and deposit or withdraw from that account. When they put input into these they select submit and an updated balance for that account will appear. If they choose to click the transaction button then a list box will show all of the users previous transactions. I hope that makes sense.

My problem currently is I don't know how to to add my classes and methods from my accounts.cs and dont know how to add my methods in the form1.cs into the buttons. What I mean by this is when the user selects submit I dont know what code to write in the buttonSubmit.

If anyone could please help me or give me some code to try out Id be so grateful. Im new to this and dont want to give up.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static partc.Accounts;

namespace partc
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    

    // declare all the accounts

    private Everyday _everydayAcct;

    private Investment _investmentAcct;

    private Omni _omniAcct;


    // to hold active account based on radio button selection

    private Accounts _accounts;



    private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      



    }

    // Display Balance
    private void DisplayBalance(Accounts account)
    {
        textBoxDispkayBalance.Text = $"{account.AccountType}{account.Balance:$#,##0.00}";
    }

    // Deposit Amount
    private void DepositAmount(Accounts account)
    {

       

    }

    // Withdraw Amount
    private void WithdrawAmount(Accounts account)
    {
       
    }


    // Display Everyday
    private void DisplayDetails(Everyday account)
    {

        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Everyday Account");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Balance:" + account.Balance);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Deposit: " + account.Deposits);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Withdrawal:" + account.Withdrawals);
    }


    // Display Investment
    private void DisplayInvestment(Investment account)
    {

        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Investment Account");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Balance: " + account.Balance);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Deposit: " + account.Deposits);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Withdrawal:" + account.Withdrawals);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Interest Rate: " + account.InterestRate + "%");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Overdraft $0.00");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Fee: " +account.Fees);
    }


    // Display Omni
    private void DisplayOmni(Omni account)
    {

        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Omni Account");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Balance: " + account.Balance);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Deposit: " + account.Deposits);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Withdrawal:" + account.Withdrawals);
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Interest Rate: " + account.InterestRate + "%");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Overdraft $100.00");
        listBoxTransactions.Items.Add("Fee: " + account.Fees);
    }


    // Shows account transaction details in list box
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radioButtonEveryday.Checked){
            
            // Display everyday details
        }
        if (radioButtonInvestment.Checked)
        {
            // Display investment detials
        }
        if (radioButtonOmni.Checked)
        {
            // Display Omni detials
        }
    }




    private void textBoxDispkayBalance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }


    // Clear Data
    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButtonEveryday.Checked = false;
        radioButtonInvestment.Checked = false;
        radioButtonOmni.Checked = false;
        textBoxDeposit.Clear();
        textBoxWithdraw.Clear();
        textBoxDispkayBalance.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Accounts.cs

```
using System;

namespace partc
{
public abstract class Accounts
{

    public int AccountNumber { get; private set; }

    public string AccountType => $"{this.GetType().Name} Account";

    public abstract decimal Overdraft { get; protected set; }

    public decimal Opening { get; protected set; }
    public decimal Deposits { get; protected set; }
    public decimal Withdrawals { get; protected set; }
    public decimal Interest { get; protected set; }
    public decimal Fees { get; protected set; }

    public decimal InterestRate { get; protected set; } = 4m;

 
    public decimal Balance => this.Opening + this.Deposits - this.Withdrawals + this.Interest - this.Fees;

    private static Random _random = new Random();
    public static int GenerateAccountNumber() => _random.Next(100000000, 1000000000);

    public (decimal Withdrawn, decimal Fee) Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount <= 0m)
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Withdrawal amount must be positive");
        }
        decimal fee = 0;
        if (amount > this.Overdraft)
        {
            amount = 0m;
            fee = 10m;
        }
        else if (this.Balance < amount)
        {
            amount = this.Balance;
        }
        this.Withdrawals += amount;
        this.Fees += fee;
        return (amount, fee);
    }

    public decimal Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount <= 0m)
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Deposit amount must be positive");
        }
        this.Deposits += amount;
        return amount;
    }


    public class Everyday : Accounts
    {
        public decimal MinBalance { get; private set; } = 0m;
        public decimal MaxBalance { get; private set; } = 1000000000000m;

        public override decimal Overdraft { get; protected set; } = 100m;

     
    }

    public class Investment : Accounts
    {
        public decimal InvestmentFee { get; private set; } = 10m;

        public override decimal Overdraft { get; protected set; } = 100m;


    }

    public class Omni : Accounts
    {
        public override decimal Overdraft { get; protected set; } = 1000m;

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: This post looks quite similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476989/adding-deposit-class-to-windows-form

Comment: @user9938 I think theyre doing the same problem as me. Do you know how to do what im asking?

Comment: Read about "abstract class" and also about "inheritance". The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance

Comment: Here's a hint. Start by creating a new instance of each of your inherited classes (ex: `private Everyday _everydayAcct = new Everyday();`

Comment: @user9938 think that is just confusing me more

Comment: @user9938 can you please help me a bit more?

Comment: How many users have you created? Why do you keep doing it?

Comment: I wouldn't use a `listBoxTransactions` to display the summaries. A multi-line label would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Please show us the screen you've designed. I suspect that it's overly complicated and we can help you simplify it. And in turn that will simplify the code.

Comment: `public abstract class Accounts` should be `public abstract class Account`. The `s` implies a list of accounts, not a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new instances of the derived account classes and assign them to the relevant private fields.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _everydayAcct = new Everyday();
        _investmentAcct = new Investment();
        _omniAcct = new Omni();
    }
```

In the radio button click event, assign the account field with the relevant account and call the display.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButtonEveryday.Checked)
        {
            _accounts = _everydayAcct;
        }
        if (radioButtonInvestment.Checked)
        {
            _accounts = _investmentAcct;
        }
        if (radioButtonOmni.Checked)
        {
            _accounts = _omniAcct;
        }
    }
```